# WinJS Listview Styling selected

Tags: css, windows-8, css-selectors, windows-store-apps, winjs

I'm looking to change the CSS style when a WinJS Listivew .win-item is selected (via right-click || swipedown).

Essentially, I have two sets of data that will be displayed in the ListView.  One upon load (default... currently `#itemName`), and one when the item is selected, hovered, or focused. (currently `#itemValue and IMG`)

I have a `WinJS.Binding.Template` as follows:

```
<div id="itemTemplate" data-win-control'WinJS.Binding.Tempalte">
    <div id="imageContainer">
        <h4 id="itemName" data-win-bind="textContent: itemName"></h4>
        <h4 id="itemValue">$0.00</h4>
        <img src="#" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

In my .CSS file I currently have the following:

```
/** note IMG and #itemValue opacity previously set to 0 **/
#itemList .win-item:hover #itemName, #itemList .win-item:focus #itemName {opacity 0;}
#itemList .win-item:hover IMG, #itemList .win-item:focus IMG{opacity 0;}
#itemList .win-item:hover #itemValue, #itemList .win-item:focus #itemValue{opacity 0;}
```

I would like to maintain this styling when an item is selected, but is not actively focused, or being hovered over.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want `::selection`.  Run your app from Visual Studio, select an item, and then go back to VS and look at the DOM Explorer.  Click "Select Element" right underneath the DOM Explorer tab.  Then click on your selected item in your app.  This brings you back to VS.  Take a look at the **Styles** and **Trace Styles** panes, which are on the right hand side at least in Visual Studio Ultimate.  You'll see that `::selection` is what styles the selected item.  Just set `opacity 0` in your own CSS file for `::selection`.

If you want to play with this in a sample app, look at the [HTML ListView Essentials sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-basic-usage-sample-fcc451db) on MSDN.

EDIT: Try `.win-selectionbackground`:

```
.win-selectionbackground {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: This works for overriding the default styles of the ::selection itself.  What I need to do is change the opacity of several divs//etc. inside the template of the list item.  Some are becoming visible, some are becoming invisible.  Maybe I am missing something additional here?

Comment: Try .win-selectionbackground.

Comment: I didn't do a very good job of explaining my problem.  I edited my question to clarify.  And added more code.  Hopefully it makes a bit more sense.  The opacity changes need to be made to individual elements (currently #itemName, #itemValue, and the IMG) on a .win-item in the WinJS.UI.ListView... not to the entire selection.  Thanks for your continued efforts.